# How can i fix Could not resolve com.mapbox.maps:android:10.13.0. error

Tags: react-native, compiler-errors

Here's my build. gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        RNMapboxMapsImpl = "mapbox" // required for v10

        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```

I ran into Could not resolve com.mapbox.maps:android:10.13.0. 
I tried to change to password = "my token" but it i still have the same error